# Combine multiple vectors (results of function) into one with template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stdvector

I'd like to have a templated function taking in a `vector<T> v` and a function op, mapping `T` to `vector<U>` and would like to concatenate the results of applying `f` to every element vector of `v` to return a `vector<U>` = [ Elements of op(v[0]), Elements of op(v[1]) ...].

A working option I found was adding an example in the function to allow for template deduction:

```
template <typename Container>
Container& concat(Container& c1, Container const& c2) {
  c1.insert(end(c1), begin(c2), end(c2));
  return c1;
}

template <typename Container, typename UnaryOperation, typename U>
inline auto to_vec_from_vectors(Container& c, UnaryOperation&& op, U& ex)
    -> std::vector<U> {
  std::vector<U> v;
  for (auto& e : c) {
    std::vector<U> opv = op(e);
    concat(v, opv);
  }
  return v;  
}
```

But naturally I'd like to produce the same result with only the two parameters. 
My attempt [replacing `U` with `decltype(*std::begin(op(*std::begin(c))))`]:

```
template <typename Container, typename UnaryOperation, typename U>
inline auto to_vec_from_vectors(Container& c, UnaryOperation&& op, U& ex)
    -> std::vector<decltype(*std::begin(op(*std::begin(c))))> {
  std::vector<decltype(*std::begin(op(*std::begin(c))))> v;
  for (auto& e : c) {
    std::vector<decltype(*std::begin(op(*std::begin(c))))> opv = op(e);
    concat(v, opv);
  }
  return v;  
}
```

Unfortunately this didn't compile. I'm also worried of wasting time if op is complex method.

This gave:

```
error: conversion from ‘std::vector<U>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<const U&, std::allocator<const U&> >’ requested

error: forming pointer to reference type ‘const U&
```

...
so it seems to be related to 'const'.

How would this variant be corrected? Are there better alternatives?

Comment: The problem is that your `decltype(...)` gives you `const U&`, not `U`. Hence the compiler error.

Comment: Why do you keep `U` and `ex` in the second case?

Comment: Not related to your issue, but depending on `U` you likely want to move when concatenating instead of just copying, e.g., `v.insert(end(v), std::make_move_iterator(begin(opv)), std::make_move_iterator(end(opv)));`. or overload `concat` and `std::move(opv)` when calling `concat`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dereferencing a container iterator yields a reference (or a const reference, if the container was const), which is why `decltype(*std::begin(op(*std::begin(c))))` yields `const U&` according to your compiler error (and not `U`).

You can fix this by either removing the reference again with [std::remove_reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) (or, if you want to also remove `const` and `volatile`, [std::remove_cvref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref)), or by just asking the vector for what it actually stores:

`decltype(*std::begin(op(*std::begin(c))))` -> `typename decltype(op(*std::begin(c)))::value_type`

I have gone ahead and removed the unneeded `U& ex` parameter.

```
template <typename Container, typename UnaryOperation>
inline auto to_vec_from_vectors(Container& c, UnaryOperation&& op)
    -> std::vector<typename decltype(op(*std::begin(c)))::value_type> {
  std::vector<typename decltype(op(*std::begin(c)))::value_type> v;
  for (auto& e : c) {
    std::vector<typename decltype(op(*std::begin(c)))::value_type> opv = op(e);
    concat(v, opv);
  }
  return v;  
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/wFx2In)

You can also avoid the triple repetition of the `decltype` chant by naming it:

```
template <typename Container, typename UnaryOperation>
using applied_op_t = typename decltype(std::declval<UnaryOperation>()(*std::begin(std::declval<Container>())))::value_type;
```

Comment: You can use `auto` for `opv` to void the repetition, and apparently `decltype(to_vec_from_vectors(c, op))` works for `v` (not 100% sure about the legality of this).

Comment: @Holt Or you skip the trailing return type... But this code has a lot of confusions in general. I decidedly did not attempt to perfect this as it's severely underspecified ;)

Comment: You cannot skip the trailing return type in C++11.

Comment: @Holt Ooops, totally missed the language tag. My bad!

Comment: Wow... That really deserves an up! It's too much to follow!