# Combine all elements from couple of vectors into one using templates

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am trying to combine couple of vectors into one using templates, but I can't make it work because of the compiler error:

```cpp
error: no matching function for call to   'to_vec_from_vectors(std::vector<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >&)'
```

The code is pretty straightforward. I have two functions, one is iterating via array of vectors, another is adding all the elements to the result vector. Appreciate any help. I have the following code:

```cpp
template <typename Container>
Container& concat(Container& c1, Container const& c2)
{
    c1.insert(end(c1), begin(c2), end(c2));
    return c1;
}

template <typename Container>
inline auto to_vec_from_vectors(Container& c) -> std::vector<typename decltype(*std::begin(c))::value_type>
{
    std::vector<typename decltype(*std::begin(c))::value_type> v;

    for (auto& e : c)
    {
        concat(v, e);
    }

    return v;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> malwares1 = {"Malware1", "Malware2"};
    vector<string> malwares2 = {"Malware3", "Malware4"};
    vector<vector<string>> mVector = {malwares1, malwares2};

    vector<string> malwares3 = to_vec_from_vectors(mVector);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"can't make it work because of the compiler errors"* Please share that error with us.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use `std::vector::insert` or `std::copy` from `<algorithm>`?

Comment: Yes. To have common methods that combine all the elements. My compiler do not have <algorithm> header.

Comment: My bad, didn't read the question fully.

Comment: This looks eerily similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023756/combine-multiple-vectors-results-of-function-into-one-with-template

Comment: Yes, this is the one I took as an example, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: @Oleg Ironically, your problem is exactly the one explained in the answer to that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*std::begin(c)` returns `vector<string>&`, you cannot store reference to vector in another vector, use `remove_reference_t` to discard it:

```
template <typename Container>
inline 
auto to_vec_from_vectors(Container& c) ->   std::vector<typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::begin(c))>::value_type>
{

    std::vector<typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::begin(c))>::value_type> v;

    for (auto& e : c)
    {
        concat(v, e);
    }

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The type `typename decltype(*std::begin(c))::value_type` seems to be what is giving you problems. `typename Container::value_type::value_type` [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7340c5969b293032).

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <typename Container>
Container& concat(Container& c1, Container const& c2)
{
    c1.insert(end(c1), begin(c2), end(c2));
    return c1;
}

template <typename Container>
inline auto to_vec_from_vectors(Container& c) -> std::vector<typename Container::value_type::value_type>
{
    std::vector<typename Container::value_type::value_type> v;

    for (auto& e : c)
    {
        concat(v, e);
    }

    return v;
}

int main()
{
    using std::vector;
    using std::string;

    vector<string> malwares1 = {"Malware1", "Malware2"};
    vector<string> malwares2 = {"Malware3", "Malware4"};
    vector<vector<string>> mVector = {malwares1, malwares2};

    vector<string> malwares3 = to_vec_from_vectors(mVector);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I decided to use remove_reference_t, but thank you anyway.